# printing the same line without repeating

Tags: python-3.x

I know that this topic was discussed here in many variations but I didn't find the solution to my problem. for example sample code like this

```
            ages = {}
            ages['Sue'] = 23
            ages['Peter'] = 19
            ages['Andrew'] = 78
            ages['Karren'] = 45

            for key in ages:
             if ages[key] >30:
               print("names",key, end = " ")
```

Output is : names Andrew names Karren,

how to do: names Andrew Karren

Comment: If you only want to print something once, it might be best *not* to put it in a `for` loop.

Comment: Print "names" before the for loop. Inside the loop, print the keys.

Answer (score 1):

Your snippet:

```
for key in ages:
    if ages[key] >30:
        print("names",key, end = " ")
```

will print `"names <the-name>"` for *all* names such that `ages[key] > 30`. So, if you have more than one name, `"names"` will be printed more than once. That's what `for` loops are for and what they do: they execute code repeatedly.

Therefore, it stands to reason that if you don't want the literal `"names"` to be printed repeatedly, then you should likely move the code that prints `"names"` outside of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

```
ages = {}
ages['Sue'] = 23
ages['Peter'] = 19
ages['Andrew'] = 78
ages['Karren'] = 45

print("names", end=" ") # Take this line out of the loop
for key in ages:
    if ages[key] > 30:
       print(key, end = " ")
```

Output:
names Andrew Karren